# Remove row from datagridview and also from list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have this class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProdID { get; set; }
    public string ProdName { get; set; }
}
```

Now to create a List:

```
public static List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();
```

To fill the datadridview with custom columns I use:

```
productsTable.Columns.Add("IDColumn", "ID of the product");
productsTable.Columns.Add("NameColumn", "Name of the product");

foreach (var product in Products)
{
    productsTable.Rows.Add(product.ProdID, product.ProdName);
}
```

I have a button to delete from row:

```
private void buttonDeleteProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedIndex = productsTable.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    if (selectedIndex > -1)
    {
        productsTable.Rows.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is to delete the selected product in datagridview also in the List.
 I just don't know how to bind in this situation.

Comment: `Products.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);` should remove from the `List<Product>`.

Comment: @abdul But what about when the table is scrambled or with some filtered items? The index will not be according with List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `productId` from `DataGrid` and use it to lookup the product from `List<Product>`, then you can remove it:

```
int productId = (int)productsTable.Rows[selectedIndex].Cells[0].Value;
var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == productId);
if (product != null)
    products.Remove(product);
```

Comment: Thank you! Deleting by identifying the ID, that's unique, worked very well. I had already thought about this solution, but I did not know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that foreach loop to populate the grid, you can use the `DataPropertyName` of the gridview columns and let them do the job for you:

```
productsTable.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    Name = "IDColumn",
    DataPropertyName = "ProdID",
    HeaderText = "ID of the product"
});

productsTable.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
   Name = "NameColumn",
   DataPropertyName = "ProdName",
   HeaderText = "Name of the product"
});
```

Given the code above, you can just set your products list as the DataSource of your DataGridView like this:

```
productsTable.DataSource = Products;
```

As for your question, considering you used the code above, you can delete the selected row and "refresh" the grid with the following code:

```
if (productsTable.CurrentRow != null)
{
   Products.RemoveAt(productsTable.CurrentRow.Index);
   productsTable.DataSource = Products.ToList();
}
```

**EDIT:** Just to make sure you delete the right product in the case the indexes differ, you can delete items like this:

```
if (productsTable.CurrentRow != null)
{
   Product prod = (Product)productsTable.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
   Products.Remove(prod);
   productsTable.DataSource = Products.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I'm already using abdul's one, deleting according to ID, but your solution is nice too!